# MVVM combining several views

Tags: c#, mvvm, listbox, xamarin.forms

I'm developing an app in Visual studio using Xamarin and MVVM light. My app will have a settings page (view) with several main categories and when the user clicks one of them I want a new view to appear with detailed settings for that specific category.

My question is rather simple, but after spending 2 hours on google I've finally given up. Is it possible to combine these detailed settings in one file/view, instead of having one view for each and everyone, since this will give 6+ views just for settings.

I've read something about using listboxes, contentviews and observablecollection but I haven't really understood how everything works.

For example:
The settings screen will show a list of categories such as: Alert options, device options, configure status etc... Each of these categories have their own options such as: turn on/off sound, vibration, screen dimming. Different kinds of alerts and so on.. I'm wondering if I can achieve this without a view for each category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can achieve it all in one view, it's all about how you want to design the user interface of your application.

It's all up for you to decide. Do you want to show all the detailed options at once, or have them show up once a category is clicked. Do you want it to work like an "accordion" type group where once you click one group, the others collapse, etc.

On mobile phones often the best practice is exactly what you described, clicking on a group of options loads a new screen with just those options. Users can use the back button to go back to the previous screen, they can see the detailed options without additional clutter, it's pretty common and nice and clean.

I am not sure why you think having 6+ views just for settings is somehow bad. You should structure your project into appropriate folders for easier organization.

Even if you wanted all the options to be on a single screen, I would still advise that you split them up into different files for easier maintenance and readability, then put them together inside one parent view as layout components of some type.

More files is usually a lot cleaner, better and more maintainable than one giant file with everything in it.

Of course, there is such a thing as too many files, so just use some common sense.

In your example, I see nothing wrong with having a folder inside your Views folder titled "Settings" then having separate appropriately named files for each of the sections.

If you have an idea of how else you would like to present this information, please elaborate on it so we can offer suggestions.

Comment: I see. I was just thinking that maybe xamarin or mvvmlight had some superMegaAwesome way of doing it, but after reading your answer I think I'll go in the "separate files direction", it seems easier. Thanks!